# Jquery datatables - pagination button alignment

Tags: jquery, datatable

Datatables pagination button is displaying on underneath of number of records. But i want to be on right side (equal to number of records message). Please look into the below images, this what i'm getting.

[image]

from firebug - inspect code in my page :

```
<div id="products1_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries</div>
<div id="products1_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate fg-buttonset ui-buttonset fg-buttonset-multi ui-buttonset-multi paging_two_button">
</div>
```

Comment: could u make a fiddle for this?

Comment: You can see my previous jsfiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/21/

Comment: Im not able to see it there.. all i can see are column1, column 2 etc

Comment: Sorry , i'm not able to simulate in jsfiddle. Because jsfiddle in working, but not working in my page.

Comment: Updated the question section , please look into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to Expand your form dialog

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
autoOpen: false,height: 300,width: 300, modal: true,resizable: false,
buttons : {
```

i changed that to

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
autoOpen: false,height: 300,width: 600, modal: true,resizable: false,
buttons : {
```

You can check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/22/)

**Updated**

[image]